# Adding conditional row borders to datatables DT in R

Tags: r, datatables, dt

I'm trying to add row borders in the middle of a datatable to separate the information more clearly, but haven't had any luck so far. Lets take `mtcars` datatable as example and an auxiliar vector which will define the rows where I want the borders, such as `aux=c(3,6,8)`

How can I define the row borders with this `aux` vector? Is it possible to do with functions like formatStyle? The final table should be something like this: [final table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMt5E.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(DT)

dat <- mtcars
aux <- c(3,6,8)
dat$hiddenColumn <- 0
dat$hiddenColumn[aux] <- 1

datatable(dat, 
          options = list(
            columnDefs = list(
              list(visible = FALSE, targets = ncol(dat))
            )
          )) %>%
  formatStyle(0:ncol(dat), valueColumns = "hiddenColumn",
              `border-bottom` = styleEqual(1, "solid 3px"))
```

[image]

Comment: Spot on! Thank you very much